# SQLServer epoch time null date

Tags: sql-server

I have a date column in the table which gets values from csv file. Right now if the date value is null, 1900/01/01 is getting inserted. How can I change it to empty string?

Thanks

Comment: How are you populating the table from the csv file?  This should be a property of the import process.

Comment: Are you saying the value in the CSV is "01/01/1900" and you want it to import as NULL?

Comment: I am using the SQLSERVER->Import data facility.  There are 8 csv files that I import separately into 8 temp tables. I need to put all of these temp files into one employee table. One of the column "EndDate" is sometimes null.when Iam inserting these dates from temp tables to employee tables it is inserting '1900/01/01' for the end date column.

Comment: If you still finding it difficult to do the just check if there is a value with date "01/01/1900" in your date column, if not then import the data and Update your table set Date.Column = null WHERE Date = '19000101'

Answer (score 0):

In you CSV file select the column and change its type to **simple text** and then try to import the data.

Comment: I open it in excel..I do not see the option simple text..can you tell me in detail

Comment: Open you excel sheet, go to  Home tab then on your ribbon look for Numbers section and on top there will be a drop down list of data types in column, SELECT the date column in your sheet and that drop down list will show you its current type set to. go to drop down list and select **Text** or **General** what ever works for you try both.